# R plumber return error and object from env in response payload

Tags: r, try-catch, plumber

I'm currently building an API service in R using plumber. I was wondering if a function within my app errors out, is there a way to tryCatch it in such a way that I can return both the error itself and an object that exists in the environment at the time of the error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes, provide same samples so it is possible to build something around it.

Longer answer : this is the default error handler

```
defaultErrorHandler <- function(){
  function(req, res, err){
    print(err)

    li <- list()

    if (res$status == 200L){
      # The default is a 200. If that's still set, then we should probably override with a 500.
      # It's possible, however, than a handler set a 40x and then wants to use this function to
      # render an error, though.
      res$status <- 500
      li$error <- "500 - Internal server error"
    } else {
      li$error <- "Internal error"
    }


    # Don't overly leak data unless they opt-in
    if (getOption("plumber.debug", FALSE)) {
      li["message"] <- as.character(err)
    }

    li
  }
}
```

As you can see towards the ends, you can use the `plumber.debug` option to return more information about the error. What you can also do is provide your own error handler.

```
pr <- plumb("plumber.R")
yourErrorHandler <- function(){
  function(req, res, err, ...){
    #do stuff, set res status you want
  }
}
pr$setErrorHandler(fun = yourErrorHandler)
```

Documentation seems to be lacking at moment for this subject.
https://www.rplumber.io/docs/rendering-and-output.html#error-handling